# docker-compose.yml compact common configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Having the `docker-compose.yml` file below, which contains n container with same configuration (`image`, `volumes` etc) **except** the `command` attribute. Is there away to write it without repeats? then if I'll have to change some configuration I could do it in one place instead of changing all occurrences.

One option is to use the variables as I used in the `image`, but that's won't solve issue where I want to add another `volume` to all of the containers.

P.S - don't care to change to version 3 if needed.

```
version: '2'
services:
  container1:
    image: ${CONTAINER_IMAGE}
    user: my_user
    hostname: my_hostname
    command: unique running command for container1
    env_file:
      - 'docker.env'
    volumes:
      - ./builds/image:/image
      - ~/workspace/component1:/component1
      - ~/workspace/component2:/component2
    links:
      - db:db
      - elastic-docker:elastic-docker
      - graphite:graphite-docker
      - zookeeper:zookeeper
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq

  container2:
    image: ${CONTAINER_IMAGE}
    user: my_user
    hostname: my_hostname
    command: unique running command for container2
    env_file:
      - 'docker.env'
    volumes:
      - ./builds/image:/image
      - ~/workspace/component1:/component1
      - ~/workspace/component2:/component2
    links:
      - db:db
      - elastic-docker:elastic-docker
      - graphite:graphite-docker
      - zookeeper:zookeeper
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq

  container3:
    image: ${CONTAINER_IMAGE}
    user: my_user
    hostname: my_hostname
    command: unique running command for container3
    env_file:
      - 'docker.env'
    volumes:
      - ./builds/image:/image
      - ~/workspace/component1:/component1
      - ~/workspace/component2:/component2
    links:
      - db:db
      - elastic-docker:elastic-docker
      - graphite:graphite-docker
      - zookeeper:zookeeper
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq

  #and so on..
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `extends` keyword to reuse the config of your first container

```
version: '2'
services:
  c1:
    image: alpine
    command: echo 1
  c2:
    extends: c1
    command: echo 2
```

or using a second file for the template

```
version: '2'
services:
  template:
    image: alpine

version: '2'
services:
  c1:
    extends:
      file: template.yml
      service: template
    command: echo 1
```

but you should only use different configurations if it is absolutely required, because without you can deploy it as a service and easily scale it with `docker service scale service=3` or with docker-compose (v3)

```
 deploy:
   mode: replicated
   replicas: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environment variables. Or else what you really need is a templating engine. There are many templating engines available. One that I have used in past is `confd`. You can get a quick start guide on the same at below link

https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd/blob/master/docs/quick-start-guide.md

This will allow you to loop and have different volume mappings and different container count using `toml` config files.

You can even use BASH based loop and scripting to generate the compose file. But it would start becoming tough to maintain your file.

PS: Some links you might be interested in:

https://theagileadmin.com/2015/11/12/templating-config-files-in-docker-containers/

http://steveadams.io/2016/08/18/Environment-Variable-Templates.html

http://tarunlalwani.com/post/simple-parameterized-config-files-docker/